# w14 and w15 namespaces issue in docx4j

Tags: docx4j

I am working with getting the XML structure(document.xml) of a MS-WORD 2010, the problem is some namespace is not included upon retrieving the XML.

This is my code so far:

```
input = FileUtils.openInputStream("C:\doc2010.docx");
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(input);
MainDocumentPart documentPart = new MainDocumentPart();
documentPart.init();
documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

System.out.println("XML : " + documentPart.getXML());
```

This is the part where the output and the **expected** output differs:

**Expected output**

```
<w:rPr>
    <w:b/>
    <w:color w:val="EEECE1" w:themeColor="background2"/>
    <w:sz w:val="72"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="72"/>
        <w14:glow w14:rad="228600">
        <w14:schemeClr w14:val="accent4">
        <w14:alpha w14:val="60000"/>
        <w14:satMod w14:val="175000"/>
        </w14:schemeClr>
    </w14:glow>

    <w14:shadow w14:blurRad="41275" w14:dist="20320" w14:dir="1800000" w14:sx="100000" w14:sy="100000" w14:kx="0" w14:ky="0" w14:algn="tl">
        <w14:srgbClr w14:val="000000">
            <w14:alpha w14:val="60000"/>
        </w14:srgbClr>
    </w14:shadow>

    <w14:textOutline w14:w="12700" w14:cap="flat" w14:cmpd="sng" w14:algn="ctr">
        <w14:solidFill>
            <w14:schemeClr w14:val="tx2">
                <w14:satMod w14:val="155000"/>
            </w14:schemeClr>
        </w14:solidFill>
        <w14:prstDash w14:val="solid"/>
        <w14:round/>
    </w14:textOutline>

    <w14:textFill>
        <w14:solidFill>
            <w14:schemeClr w14:val="bg2">
                <w14:tint w14:val="85000"/>
                <w14:satMod w14:val="155000"/>
            </w14:schemeClr>
        </w14:solidFill>
    </w14:textFill>
</w:rPr>
```

**Output**

```
<w:pPr>
    <w:jc w:val="center"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:b/>
        <w:color w:val="EEECE1" w:themeColor="background2"/>
        <w:sz w:val="72"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="72"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
```

It seems that the namespace w14 is removed or not included.

Answer (score 0):

docx4j has partial support for w14 and w15 namespace content, in the following packages:

- [org.docx4j.w14](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/w14)
- [org.docx4j.w15](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/w15)

based on [these schemas](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/xsd/wml) in our repo

The support includes what I judged to be the significant elements, but doesn't extend to glow etc.

Comment: TBH I am very new to your project and as what I've understand about your answer is: (Correct me if I'm wrong) I won't be able to get what I wanted? Because I am actually trying to get the glow effect but unfortunately it wasn't yet supported. But nonetheless, do you have any suggestions as to how am I supposed to solve this issue?

Comment: You'd need to have a look at the [MS-DOCX] spec to see how the element is supposed to be integrated into the WML XSD, then add the relevant changes into the org.docx4j.wml package (just in RPr or RPrAbstract?)

Comment: A little hint maybe? Where do I find that [MS-DOCX]? (I'm sure I found that file/thing before but I forgot where). And what do you mean "adding relevant changes".

Comment: @JasonPlutext : Hi, do you have a guide on how do I add glow effect (myself) on docx4j? I've already gone thru [MS-DOCX] but that doesn't include on how am I suppose to implement glow on docx4j (because obviously, it is a different story). Thanks in advance.